# gotoAndPlay(1) when a video is completed

Tags: flash, actionscript, video-streaming

I am trying to create a video that can be streamed on a website. The video started with a screen grab of the video on frame one. This has the action on stop();. When this screengrab is clicked, gotoAndStop(2); is fired and the timeline moves to frame 2 and the video starts to stream. All is well... Except from when the video finishes...

When the video finishes I have tried using the code

```
on (complete) {
    gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

To go back to the origonal screen grab on frame one but it doesnt seem to budge. Does anyone have any idea why it is doing this or how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the method on your root, as the main scene timeline will not be in the scope of your method.

```
on (complete) {
    _root.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```